What is the difference between function* and function *name?
Sometimes we see generator functions declared with with function* and other times we see them declared as function *nameOfFunction.  What is the difference?
For example the range function in Lit Element is declared like this:
 * @example
 *
 * ```ts
 * render() {
 *   return html`
 *     ${map(range(8), () => html`<div class="cell"></div>`)}
 *   `;
 * }
 * ```
 */
export function range(end: number): Iterable<number>;
export function range(
  start: number,
  end: number,
  step?: number,
): Iterable<number>;
export function* range(startOrEnd: number, end?: number, step = 1) {
  const start = end === undefined ? 0 : startOrEnd;
  end ??= startOrEnd;
  for (let i = start; step > 0 ? i < end : end < i; i += step) {
    yield i;
  }
}

And the tossCoins function from the documentation is declared like this:
async function *tossCoins(count: number) {
  for (let i=0; i<count; i++) {
    yield Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'Heads' : 'Tails';
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000));
  }
}


presumably you're using function expressions, so one is a named function expression, one is not (i.e. it's anonymous)

No difference semantically, just the style. Similar as String[] args and String args[] in Java.

Odd, you haven't shown an example WITHOUT a name

@HaoWu - nothing to do with style, so your java example makes no sense in javascript

@JaromandaX I think OP meant the difference between function* fn() (asterisk after the function keyword) and function *fn() (asterisk before the function name). Since function* by itself is an syntax error. For Java part I just checked OP's top language tag to give an example to show the similarities.

@HaoWu const foo = function *() { ... }

Possible duplicate of var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {} (the spacing around the * is irrelevant) but really needs clarity from @Ole

Since function* by itself is an syntax error stick to Java - but yeah, I see now the space is what is confusing the OP

If this is just about the whitespace, I feel the question could have been simply "Is the spacing around * in a generator function declaration significant?". 10 seconds of testing out various combinations would have also answered it

There is no difference other than style. The following three are equivalent:
function* foo() { /* body */ }
function *foo() { /* body */ }
function * foo() { /* body */ }

MDN's page on generator functions shows function* together followed by whitespace, but it also explicitly documents that whitespace may be added between the tokens.
ESLint plugins like generator-star-spacing can be optionally used to encourage or enforce consistency within a project. Its default configuration does not match MDN ({"before": true, "after": false}, preferring function *foo()). Other style tools and IDE plugins/configurations may also be available.

Fun fact, you don't even need a space to make it work, but please don't.
